# Extending stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to check for more URLs

Tags: php, stripos

I am using `stripos` to modify an active navigation class,

```
<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/members/login') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>
```

It works like a charm. However I need to add another `REQUEST_URI` to check in the string and cannot figure out how to properly format the code.

I have tried:

```
, '/members/login | /members/members'
```

and others without success.

Comment: What is "a hack PHP'er " ?

Comment: @Eritrea Meaning he probably copy/paste code and sometimes it works.

Answer (score 3):

You'll just have to do it twice:

```
if(
   stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/members/login') === 0
   ||
   stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/members/members') === 0){ ...
```

Note that I switched to `===0` as I presume you wouldn't want '/someotherpartofyoursite/members/members' to match presumably. If you want it in 1 call, you can use regular expressions (see [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match)), but this is fast & clear enough in my opinion.

If the list becomes longer, it depends on whether these are the whole paths, and if they are, something like this could be more suitable:

```
$urls = array('/members/login','/members/members');
if(in_array(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH),$urls)){....
```

... but not knowing your url scheme that's a guess.

Comment: You're a genius! I had to add conditionals for each page within amemberpro but it works. Thank you Wrikken!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in single call to [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as well like this:

```
if (preg_match('#/members/(?:login|members)#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    // matched
}
```